# Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument when updating report filter through VBA

Tags: vba, runtime-error, pivot-table

I am facing the VBA error the subject of this post mention on the following code:

```
Sub test 
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cp, dep As Variant
Dim Legx, DepDtex As PivotField

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Main")
    Set cp = Sheets("LEGDETAILS").Range("E3")
    Set dep = Sheets("LEGDETAILS").Range("AX2")
    Set Legx = pt.PivotFields("Leg")
    Set DepDtex = pt.PivotFields("DepDte")

    With pt
    Legx.CurrentPage = cp
    DepDtex.CurrentPage = dep
    End With
        End Sub
```

the error appears after "with PT".
The code should change 2 Report filters of the same pivot-table.
Could you be so kind to explain me why the error and how to solve it? 
Thank you

Comment: `Legx.CurrentPage` I think is an object type, so you need to `Set Legx.CurrentPage = cp`.

Comment: FYI `Dim Legx, DepDtex As PivotField` is declaring `DtpDtex` as a `PivotField` object, and leaves `Legx` as an implicit `Variant` - ditto for `cp`. Both `cp` and `dep` should be declared `As Range`.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm not sure about `Set` here. In testing, `CurrentPage` did not expect a `Range` object. Works fine with a string or value of a range.

Comment: @DavidZemens and now I can't repro the error, seeing as my answer is functionally equivalent to OP, except for fixing variable types and explicitly stating `.Value`... hmmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In testing, something like this worked for me. I don't believe that `CurrentPage` expects a `Range` object.

Note that you should declare the type for each variable, as already pointed out in the comments. Also, the `With...End With` block is not actually being used.

```
Sub test 
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim cp As Range, dep As Range
    Dim Legx as PivotField, DepDtex As PivotField

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Main")
    Set cp = Sheets("LEGDETAILS").Range("E3")
    Set dep = Sheets("LEGDETAILS").Range("AX2")
    Set Legx = pt.PivotFields("Leg")
    Set DepDtex = pt.PivotFields("DepDte")

    Legx.CurrentPage = cp.Value
    DepDtex.CurrentPage = dep.Value
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

No longer able to reproduce your error, seeing as this code is functionally equivalent to your original code, with the exception of declaring all variable types and adding the explicit `.Value` (which are all good improvements still).

**EDIT 2:**
Able to reproduce your error, albeit sporadically, by not specifically adding the `.Value`.

Comment: Thank You, the error is gone, however I have a question.
From the new code I am using I have removed the 'set =' for "cp" and "dep" but I kept the "with" block. While your new code has kept the 'set=' and removed the "with" block.
What's the difference and what makes one option better than the other?

Comment: `Set` is for a `Range` variable. I assume you have not changed the variable declaration to `As Range` for `cp` and `dep`? As far as the `With...End With`, this is a different issue. I removed it because you are not actually using it. If you were, there would be a reference to a property/method of the *pivot table* within the `With...End With` block, and that reference would begin with the period `.`. You don't have that going on.

Comment: See the [`With` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) documentation for more detail.